# Relation between "expect" and "faith"

Tags: terminology

According to Merriam-Webster

> **expect** - verb; to consider probable or certain.
>
> **faith** - noun; something that is believed especially with strong conviction

The verb linked with the word faith is the word **believe**

> **believe**, verb, to consider to be true or honest

So, in certain degree, both believe (faith) and expect appear to be the same if we expect something to be true. What's the relation between the two?

Comment: You say *It seems that there is a way that expect and faith can be used near-identically or near-interchangeably.* Please give an example. **Expectations** come with a degree of evidence: **faith** lacks all evidence.

Comment: @Greybeard thank you for pointing that out. I just improved the question based in your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can say that you **have good faith** in **the success** of some enterprise, for instance, and rather synonymously that you **expect** this enterprise **to be successful** ([ref.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+good+faith+in%2Chave+good+faith+that&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20good%20faith%20in%3B%2Cc0)).

In both case what is at work is *belief*.